# How to save edited content in html

Tags: python, html

I've been searched for a few days and find no right answers.
I have a local and static html file.

```
<html>
<div contenteditable=true>
    changes/fixes
    yyy
    uuu
    iii
</div>
</html>
```

I open it with IE and edit the content.
After that, I want to save it to another local static html file including what I've changed.

How can I achieve this? Maybe a button on the page to call a Python script, I guess? Is there any possibility?

PS:  I've found answers like jQuery+css/php+mysql, but it cannot meet my requirement. I just want to save it local and as a static html file.

Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: What's wrong with using a text editor?

Comment: @AndrewJohnson I have to edit it through browser in my project. Is it impossible?

Comment: I don't want to say it is impossible. It is just highly unusual. Browsers are for browsing and editors are for editing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using jQuery, you can get the current state of the file (or *DOM*) like this:

```
jQuery(document.body).html()
```

[Here's some basic example of this idea in action](http://jsfiddle.net/dw76eLer/), where you press a button and the html is written inside the output div.

This gets you half-way, What you want to do now is write this output in a file, and for that you can use the [FileSystem API](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/).

Since you're using IE, this could work for you:

```
function Save(data)
{
    var sys  = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
    var file = sys.CreateTextFile("output.txt", true);
    file.WriteLine(data);
    file.Close();
}
```

Comment: This assumes that he can add javascript to the page, or in other words *edit* the page.

Comment: Maybe this could work as a bookmarklet?

Comment: Well he mentions using a "button that calls a local Python script", so I assume he can, otherwise yeah it would be a lost cause lol.